# In Android 13, reading a private key from Android keystore is throwing an exception

Tags: openssl

Using Android 11, I have added a private key and device certificate in the Android Keystore and am able to retrieve it successfully whenever needed.

Recently we started migrating to Android 13 and the following exception happens when reading the private key.

**CallStack:**

```
com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: **java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000c4:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:INVALID_INTEGER**

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:311)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:366)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at f.n.e(PrivateKeyProcessor.java:7)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.trimble.ctct.ski.SKI.storePrivateKeyCallback(SKI.java:5)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.trimble.ctct.ski.SKI.fullSKIProcess(Native Method)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.trimble.ctct.ski.SKILibraryWrapper.fullSKIProcess(Unknown Source:2)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.ctct.darkskies.SKIService.onStartCommand(SKIService.java:25)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4685)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2181)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR: Caused by: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000c4:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:INVALID_INTEGER

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$Parser.generateItem(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:147)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:309)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         ... 16 more

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR: Caused by: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000c4:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:INVALID_INTEGER

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.fromX509DerInputStream(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:103)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509DerInputStream(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:261)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509DerInputStream(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:251)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$Parser.generateItem(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:137)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         ... 17 more

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000c4:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:INVALID_INTEGER

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.d2i_X509_bio(Native Method)

07-07 16:07:26.834  2049  2049 E PRIVATE_KEY_PROCESSOR:         at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.fromX509DerInputStream(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:97)
```

I explored on internet and didnot fine any clue.